# how to release uibuttons object in for loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, for-loop, uibutton

I am looping  uibuttons object in for loop for some count and when i have to release the object and unfortunately i supposed to work with non-ARC application

this is the code i have done

```
for (UIButton *btn in [self.locationScrollView subviews])
{
    if ([btn tag]==1)
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteLeft.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else if ([btn tag]==8)
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteright.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whitemid.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to release any object unless you are creating it. Here `btn` is just a pointer to your button object. Do not release it.

```
 [self.locationScrollView subviews]
```

Returns an array of  sub views (may be buttons). You are just performing [**Fast Enumeration**](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/fast-enumeration-clarifications.html) on that array.